# react-native, Android Freshchat isFreshchatNotification not handling firebase remote message

Tags: react-native, freshdesk

I'm trying to integrate `react-native-freshchat-sdk` to react native app, but when firebase remote message is coming, freshchatNotification is 0, but it should be 1. Even if I pass `notification` to Freshchat.handlePushNotification nothing happens. I assume Freshchat.handlePushNotification should navigate the user to the conversation

*Actual result*

1. freshchatNotification is 0 if it is fcm notification
2. Freshchat.handlePushNotification(notification) does nothing

*Expected result:*

1. freshchatNotification should be equal 1 if it is fcm notification
2. Freshchat.handlePushNotification(notification) should navigate the user to the chat

```js
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging'
import { Freshchat} from 'react-native-freshchat-sdk'
//...
useEffect(() => {
const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(notification => {
Freshchat.isFreshchatNotification(notification, (freshchatNotification) => {
    Freshchat.handlePushNotification(notification);
        if (freshchatNotification) {
            Freshchat.handlePushNotification(notification);
        } else {//...}
})
});
return unsubscribe
}, [])
```

See push notification payload below:
[image]

Comment: I passed notification.data to Freshchat.isFreshchatNotification, Freshchat.handlePushNotification and everything worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faced similar issue, worked by passing `notification.data` instead of direct notification object to `Freshchat`

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(notification => {
  Freshchat.isFreshchatNotification(notification.data, (freshchatNotification) => {
    Freshchat.handlePushNotification(notification);
        if (freshchatNotification) {
            Freshchat.handlePushNotification(notification.data);
        } else {//...}
  })
  });
  return unsubscribe
}, [])
```

Comment: It helped, nice!